# Powershell Delete local user says not enough arguments

Tags: windows, powershell, get-wmiobject

I'm writing a tool to make removing local copies of AD users from laptops, but once it gets to the delete step I get the below error:

> Exception calling "Delete" with "0" argument(s): ""

The code related to it is this:

```
$UserProfile = Get-WmiObject Win32_UserProfile -filter "LocalPath Like 'C:\\users\\$str'"
$UserProfile.Delete()
```

The $str variable is called a dozen lines before

```
Get-WMIObject -ClassName Win32_UserProfile -Filter "special=false and localpath like 'C:\\users\\%'" | ForEach-Object {
    #internal logic trimmed for brevity, it just check against a previous choice the user made and if it matches sets $target to the current object
    $target = $_    
}
$str = $target.localpath.TrimStart("C:\Users\")
```

This code should delete the local user folder and the registry value if I've read the man page for these functions correctly

The jist is that I get the WMI object, trim it to just the username as a string for display purposes, use that string to re-find the WMIobject and delete it

This really should work, but I get the above error, I get a similar error if I try to use the Remove-WMIObject function too. I know I'm redoing work since I already have the WMI Object in $target, but I did it like this cause the error didn't make sense.

Edit:
The fix was to add -ComputerName localhost to the command pulling the WMI object (despite the command being able to fetch the relevant WMIobject as it previously was)
Example code:
$UserProfile = Get-WmiObject Win32_UserProfile -ComputerName localhost -filter "LocalPath Like 'C:\users\$str'"

Comment: I get this error if the user whose profile I am trying to delete is currently logged in to the computer, even if the session is detached (e.g., by fast user switching).

Comment: What happens if you hardcode a specific profile? For example, let's assume that you create a profile for testing purposes, and that you call it `testprofile`. Then,  in your code, instead of this: `$UserProfile = Get-WmiObject Win32_UserProfile -filter "LocalPath Like 'C:\\users\\$str'"` you do this `$UserProfile = Get-WmiObject Win32_UserProfile -filter "LocalPath Like 'C:\\users\\testprofile'"`. Does that work?

Comment: If I hardcode a profile path I get the same error
Exception calling "Delete" with "0" argument(s): ""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command needs an unspecified argument from the documentation that only the delete process needs: -ComputerName localhost

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_UserProfile -ComputerName localhost -filter "LocalPath Like 'C:\users\$str'"
```